# Why does WP allow duplicate pages with the same name?

Tags: duplicates

I ran into an issue yesterday where I saw duplicate versions of a few different pages with the same name & path. No extra number appended to them. I deleted the duplicates which caused an issue with the nav (which I was able to fix by pointing it to the remaining pages).

Is there something off with my configuration? I wouldn't think that duplicate pages with the same name and path would be allowed.

Comment: Did you forget to mention that default theme is in use and no plugins are enabled?

Comment: It's running a custom theme with several plugins enabled. I inherited the site so i'm not sure how long this issue was occurring.

Comment: The very first thing to do is to disable all plugins, switch to any default parent theme, enable debug and `error_reporting()` and version update. Then check again. I don't believe WordPress allows you to use the same slug twice with no changes to the vanilla installation whether they are plugins, theme functions or core modifications.

Comment: As a side note, I think I've seen that there can be multiple pages with the same slug / post_name as long as they have different parent pages. E.g. /foo/bar and /baz/bar should be ok. But as top level pages or under the same parent matching slugs should not be possible by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. It looks WPML, the translation plugin, makes a duplicate page for every translated version of a page. So we had multiples of a few pages that were translated into various languages.

Sidenote: WPML stopped working a couple months ago and none of their fixes have worked yet. So no big loss just yet.

Thanks for your help!